# O que são gerenciadores de layout e por quê deve-se usá-los?

Tags: java, swing

Quando se está desenvolvendo interface gráfica com a API [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) do java, acaba-se tendo que mexer com posicionamento de componentes na tela, o que nos induz a aprender sobre gerenciadores de layout para podermos organizar como quisermos.

Mas também há o posicionamento absoluto, onde se posiciona tudo de forma fixa,  utilizando-se um sistema baseado em [coordenadas cartesianas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_coordenadas_cartesiano), além do tamanho exato do componente.

- Mas afinal, o que são estes gerenciadores de layout?
- Qual sua importância na construção de interface?
- Por que devo utilizá-los ao invés de posicionar tudo manualmente sem um gerenciador de layout utilizando [`setBounds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds-int-int-int-int-)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precisamos levar algumas coisas em consideração:

1. Originalmente a linguagem Java foi apresentada ao mundo sem uma
   IDE
2. A máquina virtual Java é multiplataforma, os programas devem
   executar igual em Windows, MacOS e Linux (inicialmente a Sun dava
   suporte ao Windows e SunOS, e a primeira JVM a existir para Linux
   era open source, depois a própria Sun começou a suportar em ambiente
   Linux)

Sem uma IDE que ajude a posicionar os componentes (como acontece no VB e no Delphi que são as principais ferramentas a popularizar isso (temos também VisualFoxPro, PowerBuilder, e etc)) é muito difícil utilizar um posicionamento absoluto.

Além disso, o posicionamento de componentes depende do toolkit nativo de cada sistema operacional para posicionar os controles gráficos.

Assim, fica muito mais fácil (ou menos difícil) de criar interfaces gráficas definindo layouts relativos utilizando os comportamentos de cada tipo de layout disponível. Vamos dizendo onde os controles devem aparecer, mas se a tela for redimensionada por exemplo, o toolkit reposiciona todo mundo.

Porém temos dois problemas com isso, um deles é ter uma quantidade muito grande de objetos sendo criados para abstrair esse posicionamento (tipo usar um FlowLayout dentro de um Panel que está no centro de um BorderLayout). O outro é aprender que tipo de objeto de layout apresenta o posicionamento que queremos.

No entanto, as IDEs Java começaram a oferecer suporte ao desenho da interface da mesma forma que as ferramentas VB e Delphi, em especial o Forte for Java, que era baseado no NetBeans 3.0 já permitia editar interfaces muito boas. Da mesma época havia um plugin opcional para Eclipse que permitia criar formulários. Aos poucos o NetBeans ficou cada vez mais forte no suporte a esse tipo de atividade, inclusive suportando o posicionamento absoluto de controles gráficos.

O link (talvez) mais importante é o do tutorial da Sun (que agora fica na página da Oracle) sobre o uso deles [que pode ser acessado aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Esse tutorial cobre as classes de Layout do AWT (toolkit original de interface gráfica do Java) e que são usados no Swing (toolkit que foi lançado no Java 2), já para o JavaFX tem painéis com os layouts embutidos, [como pode ser visto aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html). A ideia é semelhante na ideia, porém na prática diminui a quantidade de código (mas aumenta o tamanho do download porque o JavaFX é bem maior).

Até aqui foi contexto.

> Mas afinal, o que são estes gerenciadores de layout?

São classes cujos objetos podem ser atribuídos a painéis e que descrevem como os componentes adicionados ao painel serão apresentados na tela. Cada Layout tem uma característica sendo que o mais flexível e poderoso (e que tem mais detalhes para configurar) é o [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). 
Uma pequena lista de Layouts:

- [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow) - se você não especificar nenhum Layout, o seu painel Swing assume esse. Ele cria um "fluxo" de componentes, ou seja, vai colocando eles um do lado do outro e pulando linhas. Note que isso é diferente de forçar explicitamente `setLayout(null)` em um component como Jpanel ou JFrame, que é a forma de indicar que não vamos usar layouts.
- [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) - cria uma visão de áreas centro, sul, norte, leste e oeste onde você pode colocar componentes.
- [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) - esse layout não é original da biblioteca do Java, é um projeto open source e gratuito que permite descrever o layout conforme os componentes vão sendo adicionados.

> Qual sua importância na construção de interface?

A importância disso é facilitar a interface se reorganizar de acordo com as ações do usuário. Quase que como um antepassado da visão atual de responsividade, mas claro que uma GUI Java não era a mesma usada entre as diversas plataformas, embora uma aplicação JavaSE possa se conectar a uma aplicação JavaEE.

De qualquer forma, como explicado acima, se usar uma ferramenta de construção de tela, nem vemos os layouts diretamente. Inclusive existe uma recomendação no próprio tutorial sobre usar uma ferramenta como o NetBeans para isso ([ver a nota logo no início do tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)).

> Por que devo utilizá-los ao invés de posicionar tudo por conta própria
>   usando setBounds()

Agora, sobre ***dever usar Layout Managers*** já passa a ser uma questão um pouco mais delicada. Porque na prática a importância está em a tela se reajustar mais ou menos sozinha para reagir às interações do usuário de aumentar ou diminuir a janela. O método `setBounds` atua diretamente sobre o componente no qual foi chamado para definir sua localização e tamanho, desde que o layout do componente seja nulo, ou seja, a tela fica fixa independente das ações do usuário, na prática se aumentar o tamanho da janela os componentes continuariam estacionados em seu posicionamento definido.

Comment: Boa resposta, mas não respondeu a pergunta 1, não exemplificou e não citou referencias conforme observação que deixei no box amarelo.

Comment: Sua ultima afirmativa está meio contraditória. O uso de setbounds faz justamente o oposto do que você diz(que é se reajustar sozinha, ser responsiva), logo, não é uma questão menos importante. Se espera-se algo responsivo e adaptavel, com setbounds não iremos obter isso, a propria ferramenta de construção da IDE  faz uso de um gerenciador.

Comment: Eu acho que o penultimo parágrafo é irrelevante para a questão aqui, que foi sobre o uso de gerenciadores de tela, e não sobre se web é melhor que desktop.

Comment: @Articuno ok, deixei apenas a parte que fala sobre layouts vs setBounds

Comment: `GridBagLayout`!? Veja isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuLaxbFKAcc - CC @Articuno

Comment: @Articuno sim GridBagLayout, eu disse que ele é o mais flexível e poderoso, e é, não é o mais fácil de usar. A recomendação da própria Oracle (Já era da Sun também) é usar ele para ter total controle. Isso não quer dizer que seja fácil. A maior facilidade é atingida usando uma IDE.

Comment: Acredito que essa reply tenha sido direcionada ao @VictorStafusa e não a mim.

Comment: @Articuno sim, desculpe :-) como eu estava corrigindo as coisas do texto pelos seus comentários acabei indo no automático.

Comment: caros, me desculpem a intromissão, mas esta questão creio que será importante para o site. @prmottajr depois que você finalizar sua pergunta, se puder, cite também no final um pouco do MigLayout, será uma ótima referência.

Comment: @wryel o meu objetivo inicial com a pergunta era justamente esse, que fosse mostrado, nem que de forma resumida, um pouco sobre os gerenciadores. Mas nada impede que outra pessoa responda em complemento a essa resposta :) Eu estou pensando em elaborar outra resposta complementando essa mas citando os gerenciadores.

Comment: @Articuno {sem confusão dessa vez! :-) } Eu poderia incluir os layouts mas além de não estar claro isso na pergunta, inclui o link para o guia visual e o tutorial oficial. Acho que isso duplicaria informação que está disponível. A meu ver o que tratamos nessa pergunta são as considerações de uso ou não, quando e onde usar. Isso não tem no tutorial ;)

Comment: Como assim nao está claro na pergunta? A pergunta 1 pergunta o que são, subtende-se de que poderia ser exemplificado os mais comuns, mesmo de forma resumida. O guia está em inglês, nem todos que frequentam o site(inclusive eu) falam inglês. Eu aprendi a usar os gerenciadores por pratica e teste, infelizmente não graças a esse guia. :/

Comment: @Articuno sim :) eu expliquei o que são, não imaginei que era esperado uma lista deles. Posso incluir isso sem problema, mas só mais tarde :( Sobre o inglês é verdade, não me liguei nisso. Nesse caso não seria informação duplicada, não dá para traduzir o tutorial todo, mas dá para colocar mais informações aqui também (o que a pessoa não faz para brigar por 50 pontos né?) Tem mais alguma coisa que vocês gostariam que entrasse?

Comment: Uma lista nao, porque voce teria razao, se tornaria dispendioso e sairia do escopo mesmo. Mas voce já citou um layout(o gridbag), outros comuns utilizados pelas ides são o borderlayout e o miglayuot. Demais layouts concordo que vai de cada um aprender, mas esses dois são utilizados em IDE tambem, inclusive o netbeans tem o borderlayout e o gridbaglayout como opcoes naquele criador de interface grafica. Citar eles de forma rapida(nem precisa dedicar uma explicação grande nao) assim como fez com o grid já acho que seria bastante :D

Comment: @Articuno atualizado!