# Como expandir a janela ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: java, swing

Estou tentando expandir o tamanho na tela utilizando Java Swing.
Quando eu clicar em um botão preciso aumentar a altura da tela, consequentemente aparecendo mais dois botões.

Tentei fazer isso no método abaixo, porém não dá certo:

```
    private static int ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA_VISIVEL = 320;
    private static int ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA_OCULTA = 255;
    private static final int LARGURA_INICIAL_TELA = 400;

        envioCupomFiscalView.getJbSeta1().addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            flagOcultar = !flagOcultar;
            envioCupomFiscalView.getJbImprimir().setVisible(flagOcultar);
            envioCupomFiscalView.getJbSemCupom().setVisible(flagOcultar);
            if (flagOcultar) {                  envioCupomFiscalView.getJbSeta1().setIcon(Constantes.Imagens.getSetaParaCima());
                envioCupomFiscalView.setBounds(0, 0, LARGURA_INICIAL_TELA, ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA_OCULTA);                 
            } else {                envioCupomFiscalView.getJbSeta1().setIcon(Constantes.Imagens.getSetaParaBaixo());
            envioCupomFiscalView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 320));
                envioCupomFiscalView.setBounds(0, 0, LARGURA_INICIAL_TELA, ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA_VISIVEL);
            }
        }
```

Tentei utilizando o `setBounds` e o `setPreferredSize`, porém não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Não é muito bom utilizar `setbounds`  para esta finalidade e o `preferredzise` você está apenas informando ao java qual o tamanho sugerido que ele deve assumir, porém, com o código apresentado, não dá pra saber se você está trabalhando com valores absolutos ou com layouts.

Você consegue forçar o java a mudar o tamanho usando `setSize()` mas o ideal é você trabalhar com layouts e deixar que o java ajuste o tamanho, apenas definindo no `preferredzise`.

Partindo do pressuposto que `envioCupomFiscalView` é um JFrame, tente assim:

```
envioCupomFiscalView.setSize(new Dimension(LARGURA_INICIAL_TELA, ALTURA_INICIAL_TELA_VISIVEL));
```

Recomendaçãp de leitura:

[O que são gerenciadores de layout e por quê deve-se usá-los?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290742/164151)