# JScrollPane muito curto no JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Estou com um problema relacionado ao scroll da area de texto do java swing, ele não mostra os items que estão fora da area de visão do JTextArea, independente de quantas linhas o texto possui.

vídeo do problema >>> https://youtu.be/o-Rf2QkyK8o

Esse código é para o trabalho da faculdade.

Arquivo 01:

```
package View.Fields;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import View.Elements.Terminal;
public class TerminalField extends JPanel{
    Terminal shell = new Terminal();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(shell, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    public TerminalField(){
         super();
         scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
         super.add(scroll);

         /* Gen txt for test */
         for( int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
              shell.append(i + " a\n");
         }
         shell.setEditable(true);
      }
}
```

Arquivo 02:

```
    package View.Elements;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    public class Terminal extends JTextArea{
        public Terminal(){
            super();
            super.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,150));
            super.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,150));
            super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));
            super.setEditable(false);
            super.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            super.setLineWrap(true);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Utilize `new JTextArea(rows, column)` pra definir o tamanho. Esse construtor que é usado pra definir o tamanho da textarea, se você não informar o número de linhas e colunas, eles são iniciados como zero, não sendo assim possivel o scroll saber qual a base de tamanho ele deve se basear pra exibir o conteudo fora da área visivel, mesmo que você defina o tamanho preferido como fez.

Answer (score 0):

Ao que me parece, o problema do scroll que tu estás tendo é porque o `JScrollPane` tem exatamente o mesmo tamanho do `JTextArea`. Quando tu defines o tamanho to `JTextArea`, ele fica com o tamanho fixo e corta o texto excedente.

No teu caso, tu não deverias ter definido os tamanhos máximo e preferidos para o campo de texto. Assim, o campo iria se expandir dentro do `JScrollPane` conforme o número de linhas da tua String e, como o `JScrollPane` tem o tamanho definido, a barra de rolagem ficaria "melhor" e o tamanho do container ficaria igual.

Tenta isso... Espero que ajude.

Tu também podes encontrar mais informações [nesse tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Esse é um exemplo de código que tu podes usar (extraído do link acima de forma resumida):

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
JTextArea textArea;

textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setColumns(20); //define a largura    
textArea.setRows(5);     //define a altura (em linhas de texto)
    
jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea); //adiciona à um scrollPane
```

Comment: Mesmo tirando o tamanho preferido, não funciona, pois não é somente esta a causa do problema.

Comment: Tiraste também o tamanho máximo do `JTextArea`? A definição do tamanho deve ficar toda no `JScrollPane`

Comment: A definicao de tamanho deve ser passada para a jtextarea, scrollpane nao pode ter tamanho, senao ele nao expande. Da uma lida no meu comentario abaixo da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Além de definir os tamanhos para o componente, como mencionado na [resposta do Leonardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/536106/164151), você também não inicializou o componente informando quantas linhas e colunas ele vai possuir. Por isso o comportamento esperado não ocorreu.

É com base no número de linhas e colunas que o java vai dimensionar este componente e vai definir internamente um tamanho preferido através do [gerenciador de layout](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290742/164151), e assim fazer com que o componente de scroll se ajuste ao tamanho e ao texto excedente.

Para limitar o tamanho de uma caixa de texto, você pode utilizar um container a parte, como um `JPanel`, e este sim possua o tamanho fixo que você necessita. No código em questão, é possível resolver o problema modificando apenas 2 coisas:

- iniciando o `JTexArea` corretamente, informando linhas e colunas;
- ajustando o tamanho preferido para a classe `TerminalField`.

Caso essa ultima classe não seja exclusiva para acomodar a caixa de texto, você pode criar um `JPanel` inline e jogar o scroll dentro dele.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextAreaTeste {

    public TextAreaTeste() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        f.getContentPane().add(new TerminalField());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TextAreaTeste::new);
    }

}

class Terminal extends JTextArea {

    public Terminal() {
        // aqui deve ser iniciado dessa forma
        // primeiro paramentro é numero de linhas
        // segundo parametro é numero de colunas
        super(9, 15);

        /* nao mais necessário */
//        super.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,150)); 
//        super.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,150));
//        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));

        super.setEditable(false);
        super.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        super.setLineWrap(true);
    }
}

class TerminalField extends JPanel {

    Terminal shell = new Terminal();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(shell, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    public TerminalField() {
        // aqui criei um painel pra acomodar apenas a caixa de texto
        JPanel painelTexto = new JPanel();
        // aqui eu defini o tamanho que eu quero para o componente
        painelTexto.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
        painelTexto.add(scroll);

        super.add(painelTexto);

        /* Gen txt for test */
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            shell.append(i + " a\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Também é importante comentar que você está herdando duas classes de componentes para não fazer praticamente nada do que elas já não fariam, ou que você poderia fazer sem gastar a herança. Lembre-se que em java você só consegue herdar uma classe por vez e deve-se sempre analisar com calma a necessidade de usar o recurso.

Caso as alterações que você faça nos dois componentes herdados sejam apenas as do código da pergunta, poderia fazer um método q retornasse o componente modificado.

---

Recomendado:

[O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/164151)