# Por o meu JPanel não aparece o Scroll

Tags: java, rolamento, gui, jlabel, jpanel

Estou desenvolvendo um programa onde eu tenho um `JPanel` dentro de outro `JPanel`, ao qual eu chamei de panel2. Eu adicione o `Scroll` e setei a `viewport` para este segundo o `panel2`. Contudo, conforme eu adiciono as `labels`, o `scroll` não aparece para rolar para baixo o panel. Eu achei que apenas setando a `viewport` já iria funcionar. Onde está o meu erro?

Segue o código abaixo:

**Classe EquipesXPilotos**

```
package interfaceGrafica;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

import componentes.Componentes;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EquipesXPilotos extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    static Componentes conexaoComponentes = new Componentes();
    //CadastrarPilotos conexaoCP = new CadastrarPilotos("Iniciar");
    
    static ArrayList<JLabel> listaNomes = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    static ArrayList<JLabel> listaEquipes = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    
    Object[] items = {"Vettel", "Sainz", "Hamilton", "Russell"};
    Object[] items4 = {"Ferrari", "McLaren", "Mercedes"};
    
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    DefaultComboBoxModel boxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(items);
    DefaultComboBoxModel boxModel3 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(items4);
    
    JPanel panel1 = conexaoComponentes.criarJPanel(new JPanel(), 0, 0, 500, 500);
    static JPanel panel2 = conexaoComponentes.criarJPanel(new JPanel(), 40, 130, 400, 320);
    
    //JTextArea txtA = conexaoComponentes.criarJTArea(new JTextArea(), 40, 130, 400, 320);
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    JComboBox boxPilotos = conexaoComponentes.criarJCBox(new JComboBox(boxModel), 82, 45, 100, 20);
    JComboBox boxEquipes = conexaoComponentes.criarJCBox(new JComboBox(boxModel3), 300, 45, 100, 20);
    
    JLabel lblTitulo = Componentes.criarJLabel(new JLabel("Adicione os pilotos em suas equipes"), 80, -85, 500, 200);
    JLabel lblX = Componentes.criarJLabel(new JLabel("X"), 233, -44, 500, 200);
    
    JButton btnAdicionar = conexaoComponentes.criarJButton(new JButton("Adicionar"), 195, 85, 95, 20);
    
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    
    public EquipesXPilotos() {
        editarFrame();
        addComponentes();
        editarComponentes();
    }
    
    public EquipesXPilotos(String iniciar) {
        
    }
    
    public void editarFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Cadastar Equipes");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(550, 250);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(null);
    }
    
    public void addComponentes() {
        this.add(panel1);
        
        panel1.add(boxPilotos);
        panel1.add(boxEquipes);
        panel1.add(lblTitulo);
        panel1.add(lblX);
        panel1.add(btnAdicionar);
        panel1.add(scroll);
        
        scroll.setVisible(true);
        scroll.setBounds(40, 130, 400, 320);
        
        //for(int i = 0; i < conexaoCP.numeroPilotos; i++) {
        //  boxModel.addElement(CadastrarPilotos.nomePilotos.get(i));
        //}
        
    }
    
    public void adicionarLista() {
        String nome = boxPilotos.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sobrenome = boxEquipes.getSelectedItem().toString();
        
        int x = 10;
        int y = 5;
        
        listaNomes.add(Componentes.criarJLabel(new JLabel(nome), x, y, 0, 0));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < listaNomes.size(); i++) {
            
            int largura = listaNomes.get(i).getPreferredSize().width;
            int altura = listaNomes.get(i).getPreferredSize().height;
            
            listaNomes.get(i).setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
                
            listaNomes.get(i).setVisible(true);
            panel2.add(listaNomes.get(i));
            y+=20;
        }
        
        panel2.repaint();
        
    }
    
    public void criarLabels() {
        
    }
    
    public void editarComponentes() {
        panel1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        
        panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        
        lblTitulo.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblTitulo.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        
        lblX.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28));
        
        scroll.setViewportView(panel2);
        
        btnAdicionar.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EquipesXPilotos();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == btnAdicionar) {
            adicionarLista();
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Classe Componentes**

```
package componentes;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Componentes {
    
    public static JLabel criarJLabel(JLabel label, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
        label.setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
        label.setVisible(true);
        
        return label;
    }
    
    public JButton criarJButton(JButton btn, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
        btn.setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
        btn.setVisible(true);
        
        return btn;
    }
    
    public static JTextField criarJTextField(JTextField txtF, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
        txtF.setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
        txtF.setVisible(true);
        
        return txtF;
    }
    
    public JPanel criarJPanel(JPanel panel, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
        panel.setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public JList criarJList(JList list, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
        list.setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
        list.setVisible(true);
        
        return list;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public JComboBox criarJCBox(JComboBox box, int x, int y, int largura, int altura) {
        box.setBounds(x, y, largura, altura);
        box.setVisible(true);
        
        return box;
    }
    
    public JTextArea criarJTArea(JTextArea txt, int x, int y, int largura, int altur) {
        txt.setBounds(x, y, largura, altur);
        txt.setVisible(true);
        
        return txt;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Cara, tu consegue fazer um exemplo simplificado que a gente possa reproduzir localmente? Teu código aí tem muita coisa não relacionada com o problema, fica difícil identificar o problema assim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há uma sucessão de errinhos que podem ser a causa do problema que você enfrenta.

Primeiro, você está definindo um tamanho para o scrollpane, e isso por si só já faz com que ele não crie as barra de rolagem de forma automática. o scrollpane é uma ferramenta flexivel e autorresponsiva, o melhor é sempre deixar que ele lide com o tamanho de si próprio. Apenas trate de definir um tamanho para o componente onde ele será incluso.

Outro ponto, que acredito ser a principal causa do problema, é você não se decidir qual painel o scroll pertence. Na linha:

```
panel1.add(scroll);
```

você adiciona o scroll ao `painel1` e logo abaixo, na linha

```
scroll.setViewportView(panel2);
```

você define o vierport do scroll como sendo o `painel2`, sendo que ele nem pertence a este componente. Recomendo revisar seu código e verificar a qual painel o scroll faz parte, e definí-lo como Viewport.
**Não reuse o mesmo scroll em paineis diferentes de forma alguma!**

Para que a rolagem funcione corretamente, você deve definir o painel como Viewrport do JScrollpane e adicionar este último na sua tela, algo parecido com o exemplo abaixo:

```
JFrame frame  =  new JFrame();
JPanel meuPainel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(meuPainel);//setando na instancia, não precisa chamar setViewPortView().
frame.add(scroll); // o painel é parte do scroll, q passa a ser o container dele agora
```

É altamente recomendado que se evite usar layout absoluto, através do método `setBounds`, pois isso irá tirar a flexibilidade da sua aplicação, podendo ter aparencia diferente em resoluções e telas diferentes das que você está criando a aplicação.

Recomendo a leitura: [O que são gerenciadores de layout e por quê deve-se usá-los?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290742/164151)

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela excelente resposta. Eu reli o código e realmente faz sentido o que você falou referente à adicionar aos panels e decidir de qual panel o Scroll faz parte. Na verdade o Scroll ele faz parte do panel2. 

Contudo, quando eu adiciono o scroll no `panel2` através do `panel2.add(scroll)` e depois eu defini a `viewport` do `scroll` para o `panel2`, ele acusa erro, dizendo que eu estou fazendo uma auto relação de adição.

Comment: @WalkerDeCarvalho só adiciona, remove a linha pra setar o viewport, acredito que funciona igualmente dos dois jeitos, por isso ta acusando redundancia.

Comment: @WalkerDeCarvalho esqueci de mencionar, eu nao vi onde no seu código você usa o painel2, mas ao criar um scroll e definir ele como viewport do scroll, você está adicionando o painel2 dentro do scroll, então você não deve adicionar o painel2 na sua tela, e sim, o scroll, ja com o painel2. Se não fizer assim, o scroll não funciona.

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra melhor explicar isso.

Comment: Entendi. Eu fiz a alteração conforme você havia orientado, mas imagino que por causa do layout absoluto está ocorrendo um problema. Eu fiz da seguinte forma:
Tirei o 'viewport' do código. adicionei o panel2 no panel1 (`panel1.add(panel2)`) e depois adicionei o scroll ao panel2 (`panel2.add(scroll)`). Só o que ocorre é que o scroll está sobrepondo o panel2.

Eu adiciono as labels no panel2 pelo método de adicionar labels, mas consequentemente elas não aparecem devido ao scroll sobrepor. E quando eu adiciono as labels no próprio scroll, não aparece a barra de rolagem.

Comment: @WalkerDeCarvalho o painel que tem o scroll nao deve ser adicionado a nenhum outro componente, veja a edição que fiz na pergunta com exemplo.